# Electrical change over

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

What is the correct way of changing over from one power source to another in a plant complex?

In Nigeria, we have public power source as well as power generators as alternative source when public power is not available.

Do I have to put off the load first before changing source or change source wile it is loaded?

Comment: Search for ATS, automatic transfer switch.